# not getting dual boot grub menu ubuntu12.04.2 64 bit with pre-installed windows7 64-bit

Tags: 12.04

I have pre-installed windows 7 64 bit on Lenovo G580 and then i want to install Ubuntu 12.04.2 64 bit for android sourcecode compilation.

while installing windows i partitioned HD into 3 drives c-100 GB D-197 GB G-176GB.

I installed ubuntu on D drive with "something else"  option after successfully installed Ubuntu 12.04.2 finally it will ask restart.

here it's come problem instead of showing dual boot menu windows starting ....

could you please suggest me .. how to get dual boot menu to choose which opearting system to start...

Can anyone tell me how to check whether my laptop supports 64 bit or not?

Then

I tried installing Ubuntu 12.04.2 using VMware here i am getting the following errors:

A dialog with message :

```
Binary translation is incompatible with long mode on this platform. Disabling long mode. Without long mode support, the virtual machine will not be able to run 64-bit code. For more details see http://vmware.com/info?id=152.
```

After clicking OK button: I got the following error with big Red error:

```
 This virtual machine is configured for 64-bit guest operating systems. However, 64-bit operation is not possible.

 This host supports Intel VT-x, but Intel VT-x is disabled.

 Intel VT-x might be disabled if it has been disabled in the BIOS/firmware settings or the host has not been power-cycled since changing this setting.

1. Verify that the BIOS/firmware settings enable Intel VT-x and disable 'trusted execution.'

2. Power-cycle the host if either of these BIOS/firmware settings have been changed.

3. Power-cycle the host if you have not done so since installing VMware Workstation.

4. Update the host's BIOS/firmware to the latest version.

For more detailed information, see http://vmware.com/info?id=152.
```

My laptop is a Lenovo G580.

Comment: yes, your computer supports 64 bit. try [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) & choose `recommended option`. it will give a url at end of process. Take a note of that. Reboot, if problem persists, edit your question to include the url.

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing ubuntu12.04.2 using VMware here i am getting the following errors:

A dialog with message :

Binary translation is incompatible with long mode on this platform. Disabling long mode. Without long mode support, the virtual machine will not be able to run 64-bit code. For more details see http://vmware.com/info?id=152.

after clicking ok button : i got the following error with big Red error:

This virtual machine is configured for 64-bit guest operating systems. However, 64-bit operation is not possible.

This host supports Intel VT-x, but Intel VT-x is disabled.

Intel VT-x might be disabled if it has been disabled in the BIOS/firmware settings or the host has not been power-cycled since changing this setting.

(1) Verify that the BIOS/firmware settings enable Intel VT-x and disable 'trusted execution.'

(2) Power-cycle the host if either of these BIOS/firmware settings have been changed.

(3) Power-cycle the host if you have not done so since installing VMware Workstation.

(4) Update the host's BIOS/firmware to the latest version.

For more detailed information, see http://vmware.com/info?id=152.

my laptop lenovo G580